# How can I create a model of a table with an enum in peewee 2?

Tags: python, peewee

I'm trying to create a model to describe a table with an enum field in [peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee).

I'm seeing that EnumField was removed from the peewee.py file before the 2.0 version, and I can't find anything in the current docs that outlines how to implement it. Does anyone know if I can just use CharField?

Comment: Did you ever implement an ENUM field using a custom peewee field? If so, would you mind sharing that solution with us?

Comment: Just use the ```choices``` Field attribute?

Comment: The choices field attribute didn't exist in 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there was not an EnumField prior to 2.0, but there are docs on implementing a custom field:
http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/models.html#creating-a-custom-field

I hope this helps.

Comment: coleifer should that be part of standard peewee fields? I see `choices` option but if it doesn't validate value. I remember sqlobject used to support such field.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working solution for PostgreSQL:

https://gist.github.com/b1naryth1ef/607e92dc8c1748a06b5d

Comment: Why the downvote? With some feedback, I could maybe improve my answer...